# Aggregate Function of a column if there are nulls?

Tags: sql, presto

If I am running an aggregate function on a column with numerical values such as below:

```
Select Name, count(Miles) as number from tbl
```

If some names have `null` values in `Miles` column, how will that be handled?

If it is a name that has other values it will just not be counted, but if it is name that has only null values and no numbers how will that show up in the output?

Comment: *If some names have null values in Miles column, how will that be handled?* All aggregate functions ignores NULL values. I.e. for dataset {1, NULL, 3} they will show MIN=1, MAX=3, COUNT=2, AVG=2. If some aggregate function would take NULL value into account, it must be mentioned in its description separately.

Comment: _if it is name that has only null values and no numbers how will that show up in the output?_  Well in this case name will be display with Count(Miles) = 0 as output.

Answer (score 3):

> `Select Name, count(Miles) as number from tbl`

I assume you have also `... GROUP BY Name` in your query.

> If it is a name that has other values it will just not be counted, but if it is name that has only null values and no numbers how will that show up in the output?

It will be included in the output with 0 count.

Example:

```
presto:default> SELECT name, count(value)
             -> FROM (VALUES ('a', 1), ('b', NULL)) t(name, value)
             -> GROUP BY name;
 name | _col1
------+-------
 b    |     0
 a    |     1
(2 rows)
```

(verified on Presto 327)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one maybe you got something here.

Here you can find how to handle null values please see the example below.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl
(
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
    Miles VARCHAR(10) NULL
)


INSERT #tbl VALUES('A','A'),('B','B'),('C','C'),('D','D'),
('A','A'),('B','B'),('C','C'),('D','D'),
('A','A'),('B','B'),('C','C'),('D','D'),('D',NULL)
```

> 1) First Select Query

```
Select Name, count(Miles) as number 
from #tbl
GROUP BY NAME
```

> Output

[image]

> 2) Second Select Query

```
Select Name, count(ISNULL(Miles,'YOU DEFAULT VALUE')) as number 
from #tbl
GROUP BY NAME
```

> Output

[image]